# GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile: fails for the first time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, textures, sprite, glkit

I am using `GLKTextureLoader` to load image textures into a sprite.

When I run the following code and load two sprites...

```
NSString *pathToImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/defaultProject/images/%@", [Util applicationDocumentsDirectory], fileName];
NSLog(@"path: %@", pathToImage);
self.textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage options:options error:&error];
if (self.textureInfo == nil) 
{
    NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
}
```

... it fails for the first image but not for the second.

The error is:

```
Error loading file: The operation couldn’t be completed. (GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain error 12.).
```

Does anyone know what this error means? I haven't found any information on code 12.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 12 means `GLKTextureLoaderErrorDataPreprocessingFailure` as per ([Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKTextureLoader_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/GLKTextureLoaderErrorDataPreprocessingFailure))

I think cause of error is a file corruption. Try to re-save your corrupted image.

Comment: You are right. When I change the file and leave the filename equal it works. But I can open the file in preview? So it is definitely not corrupt?! The only difference is in the filesize.

Comment: File can be ok, but it can't processed by some reason. Re-saving same file should solve your problem.